# How to write index and match in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting blank results in my worksheet when i run index and match in VBA and i dont know why...please help.

I have some data in details2 worksheet which contains ID, names, servicetype cost and dates in different columns. I also have partly similar information in another worksheet called forecast but without the dates column. Because a client can have multiple service type starting at different dates, I have matched the ID, names, servicetype and cost to extract the desired dates. But I want to write this using VBA to make it flexible because i carry out this every month and the data ranges can change. I have already tried using array formula and copied it down which work fine. but when i put it in a loop the cells output is blank. I expect date values from DETAILS2 worksheet in column N of another sheet 
    but my column N is blank...other part of the program works fine.

This is the code That I have tried which works:

```
 With Test1Ws                   
  .Range("N3").FormulaArray = "=IFNA(INDEX(DETAILS2!$A$3:$Z$780,MATCH(1, 
  (DETAILS2!$A$3:$A$780=B3)*(DETAILS2!$B$3:$B$780=C3)* 
  (details2!$X$3:$X$780=F3)*(details2!$Y$3:$Y$780=G3),0),18),0)"
  .Range("N3").AutoFill .Range("N3:N" & Test1LastRow)
 End With
```

This is the code i wrote trying to make it flexible to change the ranges:

```
 With Test1Ws
  For x = 3 To Test1LastRow
      On Error Resume Next
      Test1Ws.Range("N" & x).Value = 
      Application.WorksheetFunction.IfNa(
      Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(CurrDeIndexRng,
      Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1,(CurDeIdRng = .Range("B" & 
      x).Value) * (CurDeNameRng = .Range("C" & x).Value) * (CurDeServRng = 
      .Range("F" & x).Value) * (CurDeCstRng = .Range("G" & x).Value), 0), 
      18), 0)
   Next x
 End With
```

Comment: Is there an issue with just using your filldown and then `Columns("N").Value = Columns("N").Value`?

Comment: You cannot do an array formula using Application.WorksheetFormula.  The best method is to forget about formulas and use variant arrays and loop the rows till you find the match.

Comment: @Scott thanks for the quick advice. Could you please tell me how to go about this. I am really struggling....if i can get a head start that will be helpful. But thanks for understanding my problem

Comment: @Cyril, yeah that works fine when i used copy and paste values but my data set changes every month and i have to hardcode other related parts of the program by changing the ranges every time. Plus others will be using the macro as well and that could mess things up. thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using vba, most of the time it is better to avoid using worksheet formulas and just loop variant arrays.

```
With test1Ws
    Dim inpt() As Variant
    inpt = .Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(Test1LastRow, 7)).Value

    Dim detlstrw As Long
    detlstrw = Worksheets("DETAILS2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim search() As Variant
    search = Worksheets("DETAILS2").Range(Worksheets("DETAILS2").Cells(1, 1), Worksheets("DETAILS2").Cells(detlstrw, 25)).Value

    Dim outpt() As Variant
    ReDim outpt(1 To UBound(inpt, 1), 1 To 1)

    Dim x As Long
    For x = LBound(inpt, 1) To UBound(inpt, 1)
        outpt(x, 1) = 0
        Dim Y as Long
        For y = LBound(search, 1) To UBound(search, 1)
            If inpt(x, 1) = search(y, 1) And inpt(x, 2) = search(y, 2) And inpt(x, 5) = search(y, 24) And inpt(x, 6) = search(y, 25) Then
                outpt(x, 1) = search(y, 18)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next y
    Next x

    .Range("N3").Resize(UBound(outpt, 1), 1).Value = outpt
End With
```

Comment: Good catch; removed the other answer... managed to forget that was `.FormulaArray` when my suggestion was relative to `.Formula`

Comment: That is why we are here, to help.

Comment: @scott, thanks so much, I am going through this now and i will give you an update asap but it look good to me...Thanks stay tuned

Comment: @Scott, My wedding day was my most astonished day up until now..You are a certified magician. THANK YOU!!! it works like a charm!!!! I am so trilled..been on this for over a month. You dont have an idea how helpful this is for me man...I am very grateful...I didnt have any issue at all...Thanks man...

Comment: @Cyril, Thanks for you input as well, I am very grateful

Comment: @Scott, I will like to clarify with you why in the for loop, the var Y was not declared like the x as long...

Comment: @Scott, thanks again for the clarification...hope i can come back to you at other time...you have been very helpful... .